# Liquibase: best way to check whether a table in a different database exists in <precondition>

Tags: sql, liquibase

I have 2 databases: db 1 and db 2

I need to take different action on db 1 based on whether a table in db 2 exists or not, and I am using liquibase to record my action.

here is my solution so far

```
<preconditions onFail="CONTINUE">
    <sqlcheck expectedResult="1">
          IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DB2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE') 
                  SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0
    </sqlCheck>
</precondition>
```

The problem is: This is mssql syntax, if I try to use a different db, I need to change to use a different syntax, so what is the best way to do such thing?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried `<tableExists>` precondition http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html?
Also you can implement any logic as `<customPrecondition>` in Java.

Comment: yeah, I want to use tableExists, but that seems only apply to table in the current db, not sure how to use it check table in a different db...